# Dynamic Target.Adress excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, vlookup, target

## SOLVED (in the comments is the solution for this issue, thank you Ron)

Just signed up cause I wasn't able to find an answer to this task although I've tried really hard to get it done without bothering.

The thing is that I'm trying to make a VLookUp at specific cells every time they change it value. The cells do not exist until I ask the excel to create them using "Worksheet_Change"

The worksheet adds as many rows as I ask for and edit them with the fields that I will select.

eg. I need to put 3 process variables, so I enter "3" next to the first row ("$R$30"). By doing this change, excel adds 2 more rows (at the end of the first programed part, I get the first one which was already there, and then 2 more to complete the 3 rows that I need).

Done this part, I need to update the process definition with a "validation data" list (already done and working fine), using the info from the "process cell" ("$R$...") I need to add a definition code next to it automatically.

eg. when I select "Flow Calibration" from the validation data, I get "XD61DD" next to it.

For the first row, it works fine... I can't make it work for all the added rows.

Here is the code I've been working on: (I'm learning so, please, don't take it too hard on me, I know it's like stone age coding :P)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cant As Integer
Dim RowNumber As Integer
    If Target.Address = "$AG$30" Then
        If Range("$AG$30") <> "" Then
        cant = Range("$AG$30")
        For i = 1 To cant - 1
            Var = 30 + i
            Range("A" & Var).Select
            RowNumber = ActiveCell.Row
            Rows(RowNumber).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            rango1 = "L" & RowNumber & ":" & "Q" & RowNumber
            rango2 = "R" & RowNumber & ":" & "AF" & RowNumber
            Range(rango1).Select
            Selection.Merge True
            Range(rango2).Select
            Selection.Merge True
            rango3 = "AG" & RowNumber
            Range(rango3).Select
            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
                :=xlBetween
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        Next i
    End If
End If
```

Until here it works fine, the first part is for reference, but then:

```
Range("R30").Select
If Target.Address = "$R$30" Then
    If Range("$R$30") <> "" Then
        Range("$L$30") = Application.VLookup(Range("$R$30"), Range("$BG$3:$BH$9"), 2, False)
    End If
    If Range("$R$30") = "" Then
        Range("$L$30") = ""
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I left the "$R$30" because there is were it worked fine but I need to perform the same instruction to "$R$31", and so, when the rows are created.

I really hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

AGUS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you are interested when Target might be in the range R30:R1000.  So something like (not debugged)

```
Dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Range("R30:R1000")
If Not Intersect(Target, myRange) is Nothing then
   'consider if you need to disable events temporarily
   If Target <> "" Then _
   Target.Offset(0,-6) = Application.VLookup(Target, Range("$BG$3:$BH$9"), 2, False)
end if

'Don't forget to re-enable events if you disabled them
```

**EDIT**:  If your selection in `myRange` happens to be more than one cell, the above simplified version will not work.  You need to test one cell at a time.  One modification might be something like:

```
Dim myRange As Range, C As Range
Set myRange = Range("R30:R1000")

If Not Intersect(Target, myRange) Is Nothing Then
    For Each C In Intersect(Target, myRange)
        If C <> "" Then _
            C.Offset(0,-6) = Application.VLookup(C, Range("$BG$3:$BH$9"), 2, False)
        End If
    Next C
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I´ve tried that just now... it didn't work... "Type mismatch" at "If Target <> "" Then _"... Not sure where "disable events" could work

Comment: That can happen if `Target` is more than a single cell.  In other words, if your selection happens to be multiple cells.  See my Edit for solution.

Comment: A reason to disable events while the event handler is running is to prevent triggering of the event handler while the event handler is running.  This can lead to infinite loops.  When debugging you need to be careful since a debug stop will not re-enable the event handler --- that needs to be done manually.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I'll try it and let you know as soon as I can. Thanks again for your time and quick response.